# VS Code: Prettier splits paragraph text to multiple lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I have a long text in p tag and Prettier splits the text in this tag to multiple lines. I have 'word wrap' enabled.

How can I stop this from happening?

Before Save:
[image: long text enclosed in p tag before save]

After Save:
[image: long text split into multiple lines after save]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier is opinionated, it has only limited number of options.
If you couldn’t find what you want in https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html, so it’s not supported.

In general, better to accept Prettier behavior instead of fight against it.
The reformatting, that prettier does, doesn’t harm.

You can try to increase width.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I love prettier in general but was intrigued as I can't understand the logic of this split.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Strech VS Code Window**
Simply **stretch/widen** your VS code window and it'll get "fixed":

[image: Strech/widen your VS Code Window]

**2. Change Print Width**
As you can see from 1, it's not a real problem.
You can however also experiment with adjusting Prettier Print Width.

1. Open VS code
2. Click `Manage > Settings`
3. Type in "Prettier" and scroll down to `Prettier: Print Width` to change it.

[image: How to change Prettier Print Width]